# swift cannot assign to the result of this expression

Tags: swift

I'm kinda new to programming, so this maybe a basic question. I'm trying to work with nested arrays in Swift.

```
@IBAction func testFuncTrigger(sender: UIButton) {
    var tempTestArray = [];
    tempTestArray = [["cos",["x"]],["sin",["cos",["x"]]],"5*x"];
    tempTestArray[1] = "8*x";
    tempTestArray[1] = ["8*x"];
    tempTestArray[1] = ["e^",["sin",["x"]]];
}
```

gives the error "cannot assign to the result of this expression".

Also trying to put

```
@IBAction func testFuncTrigger(sender: UIButton) {
    var tempTestArray = [];
    tempTestArray = [["cos",["x"]],["sin",["cos",["x"]]],"5*x"];
    tempTestArray[1] += "8*x";
    tempTestArray[1] += ["8*x"];
    tempTestArray[1] += ["e^",["sin",["x"]]];
}
```

gives the errors

```
Binary operator "+=" cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject' and 'String'
```

and

```
Binary operator "+=" cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject' and '[String]'
```

and

```
Binary operator "+=" cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject' and '[NSObject]'
```

respectively.

Is there anyway to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare an array like this:

```
var tempTestArray = []
```

The type of this array will be `NSArray` because you doesn't define any type to your array. And you can not add any element into `NSArray` that way.

Give a type to your `tempTestArray` to `AnyObject` like this:

```
var tempTestArray = [AnyObject]()
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: For some reason, [] causes Swift to create an NSArray-- which you can't add objects to! A strange behavior, when it should probably just refuse to compile in a situation where it can't determine the type of the empty array.

Comment: Yup, that works, thanks a lot. I just tried the .append() function and it works now after specifying the type.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)